# What is the technical reason to forbid primitive types as key in a WeakMap?

Tags: javascript

The standard says so and there is no doubt that primitive types cannot be used as key in a `WeakMap`; but what is the **technical reason** for adding such a limitation?

I wanted to implement a simple `hash` function mapping JS values to 0-65535 and that would have been trivial by using a `WeakMap`; unfortunately I need to hash anything (including symbols and strings) but this is forbidden and I wonder why.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/why-cant-an-es2015-weakmap-have-primitive-keys) post?

Comment: @NickParsons: of course value types used as keys would need to remain in the `WeakMap` forever until explicitly removed with `delete` (the reason being that even if say the number 1234 is no more present in the data or the code I could still "recompute" it... this is not possible with object references where once an object is unreachable there is no way to get it back again). I simply fail to see what is the advantage of not allowing them and on the other hand I can see uses for a more general `WeakMap` that can use both values and references as keys.

Answer (score 1):

`WeakMap`s are designed to map one weak-referenced object to another. Primitive types such as `String`, `Number` and so on are strong-referenced and designed in a way that when you assign a `String` value to a variable it doesn't assign a reference to the source string, but copies that value to the new variable (and therefore, e.g. when you change source variable, the new one won't change).

Weakly-referenced objects are made to be garbage-collected. When it's not used by any parts of the script, it will be removed and memory will be freed. Primitive types in JS are strong-referenced (values are copied, not referenced), therefore garbage collector will never trigger the deletion of that values, and deletion of that strongly-referenced, primitive typed keys in a map (which conflicts with the whole idea of `WeakMap`).

But if you still need to use primitive values as keys to `WeakMap`, you can try some workaround like wrapping primitive value in some object and then using that object as a key.

Comment: I didn't check the source of any Javascript implementation but I'm pretty sure that strings (I mean strings like `x = "Hey, how're you?";` not `x = new String("Hey, how're you");`) are not copied because that would make no sense in a language like Javascript in which strings are immutable. I'd say that the most sensible implementation would be for example to store them in regular garbage collected objects with possibly a "short string optimization" logic for strings of a few characters as they can take less space than a pointer).

Comment: Note that despite long strings being internally garbage collected objects, are still "value types" and thus they should remain in the `WeakMap` as key until explicitly deleted (the reason is that `"a" + "b" === "ab"` so even if there are no more references to an `"ab"` string anywhere I can still recompute the value).

Answer (score 0):

Consider hypothetical function:

```
f = (i) => WeakMap([[i,2]]);
```

We would expect that once `i` is no longer referenced outside this map it will be removed from it. However, if I have code that invokes `f(3453453)` then value of `3453453` will be presumably indefinitely referenced by the interpreter and, as such, never removed from the returned map. In contrast, every time you execute code with object literal `{}` you get a new object, so you can trace if it will referencable or not.

I also expect JavaScript implementations to have many dedicated optimizations for primitive types, that could be impossible to keep compatible with checking if they are referenced or not. For example, you might be able to operate on value of `123` without having a dedicated memory location and object for it.

Comment: Of course value types used as keys would need to remain in the WeakMap forever until explicitly removed with delete (the reason being that even if say the number 1234 is no more present in the data or the code I could still "recompute" it... this is not possible with object references where once an object is unreachable there is no way to get it back again).

Comment: Right, but if you accept explicit deletion then there is nothing weak about your map, you can use basic Map instead.

Comment: I now get that your point is that you could have a map structure that is weak on reference types and strong on value types. It seem over-complicated and easily implementable with two separate maps, so I don't really see why standard should mandate its existence.